# C++ API as an Python Extension Module

Tags: c++, python, api

Can APIs written in C or C++ always be made into a library, given source code, and consequently be called from Python, due to the intrinsic callable nature of an API?

In other words, given a C/C++ API can you run a setup.py script using distutils on the source and effectively use the C/C++ API from python programs?

Comment: Well, the source code would be manually modified to use distutils.  I am going to try these suggestions and return to select an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit more involved than running a setup.py script, but there are tools to wrap C/C++ libraries so you can use them from Python. Some popular ones are:

- [Cython](http://cython.org/) - you write Python-style code, but you can cimport C libraries and call their functions. Cython code is then translated to C and compiled. There's an unsupported tool called [cython-codegen](https://github.com/cournape/cython-codegen) to automate writing a simple wrapper.
- [boost.python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python) - For wrapping C++ libraries.
- [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn2)
- [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) - Load compiled libraries and call them directly from Python. [ctypesgen](http://code.google.com/p/ctypesgen/) tries to automatically write a wrapper based on header files.

Certain projects use other tools to generate Python bindings, and they could probably be reused (with varying amounts of effort). PyQt4 uses [SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIP_%28software%29), PySide (another Qt binding) has [shiboken](http://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/shiboken), and GTK et al. have [Gobject introspection](http://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection).

Comment: For those who decide to use Cython for this, I actually wrote a small post about it, covering all the details from writing Cython source files to building them, writing setup.py - basicly all that you need to wrap your C/C++ library with Cython for Python: http://martinsosic.com/development/2016/02/08/wrapping-c-library-as-python-module.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly that simple, but basically you can do that using SWIG, which will generate the necessary wrappers to bind your python and C/C++ code.  http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no intrinsic or automated mechanism for binding a C++ API to Python. It must be done manually. The best tool I've seen for this purpose is Boost Python.

Of course, given the clean mapping between C++ Object Oriented programming and Python OO code, it shouldn't be too difficult to create a script which parses C++ headers and produces the binding declarations. [GCC-XML](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html) will give you an xml representation of parsed headers, which can be easily queried by a python script to produce the bindings. That said, there's probably a great deal of detail I've not anticipated which could prevent this approach from working.